# Need assistance in project regarding Change Detection

Tags: qgis, google-earth-engine, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, change-detection, image-classification

My task initially was to classify the area into land-use classes like forest, sparse vegetation, agriculture, river, etc 
I had done that by clustering the whole area and then reclassing it.
I had to further show some analysis and accuracy of my classification so that the change detection can be visualized.
So I need some guidance on how to approach next as I am stuck here and don’t know how to proceed further.

I am sending my code snippet of the year 2000.

I have data from 1995 to 2015 with 5 years interval

```
var poi=ee.Geometry.Point([78.032188,30.316496]).buffer(35000);
var dataset = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LT05/C01/T1_TOA')
              .filterDate('2000-01-01', '2000-12-31');
var trueColor321 = dataset.select(['B3', 'B2', 'B1']);
var tru=trueColor321.reduce(ee.Reducer.mean());
var truclip= tru.clip(poi);
var trueColor321Vis = {
       min: 0.0,
       max: 0.4,
       gamma: 1.2,
};
Map.setCenter(78.032188,30.316496, 9);
Map.addLayer(truclip, trueColor321Vis, 'True Color (321)');

var dataset1=ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LT05/C01/T1_32DAY_NDVI').filterDate('2000-01-01','2000-12-31');
var NDVI= dataset1.select('NDVI');
var ndvimean=NDVI.reduce(ee.Reducer.mean());
var ndviclip=ndvimean.clip(poi);
var visparam={
   min: 0.0,
   max: 1.0,
   palette: [
'FFFFFF', 'CE7E45', 'DF923D', 'F1B555', 'FCD163', '99B718', '74A901',
'66A000', '529400', '3E8601', '207401', '056201', '004C00', '023B01',
'012E01', '011D01', '011301'
     ]
    };
Map.addLayer(ndviclip,visparam,'NDVI',0);


//clustering
var training=ndviclip.sample({
region : poi,
scale : 30,
numPixels : 5000
 });
var clusterer=ee.Clusterer.wekaKMeans(20).train(training);
var result = ndviclip.cluster(clusterer);

Map.addLayer(result.randomVisualizer(),{},"clusters");

//forest classification
var reclass= result.remap([8,10,13,6,11,17,19],[1,1,1,1,1,1,1]);
Map.addLayer(reclass,{},'forest',0);

//water bodies 
var waterbodies=result.remap([2],[2]);
Map.addLayer(waterbodies,{},'water',0);

//urban/barren land 
var urban=result.remap([7,12,3,5,0,16,15],[3,3,3,3,3,3,3]);
Map.addLayer(urban,{},'urban/barren');

//agricultural
var agriculture=result.remap([4,8,17,19,18],[4,4,4,4,4]);
Map.addLayer(agriculture,{},'agriculture');

//sparse
var sparse= result.remap([1,9,4,14],[5,5,5,5]);
Map.addLayer(sparse,{},'sparse');
```